# BFL 7GH Jalapeno suddenly trips circuit breaker, what can I do?

Tags: mining-hardware, mining-setup, butterfly-labs

After chugging along just fine (though never at full advertised GHps always 6.5 instead of 7), my Butterfly Labs jalapeno suddenly started to persistently trip the circuit breaker all of a sudden, even if I plug it into a plug in another room, on another circuit.
The thing that seems to be important is that when the USB cable is plugged into the PC it trips the circuit and not when it is just pulling power from the outlet with no USB connection. 
It was not overheating (Around 115F), and up until last night it never happened - now it happens no matter what..

Answer (score 1):

I had one Jalapeno power supply die on me, perhaps you can source a replacement?  12V seems OK, but make sure it's rated for the amps.